# AWS security optionsn

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I am currently building a instance request form for AWS services (EC2, RDS etc) and   I am being asked to add a security portion in the request form where we can select the type of security applicable for the instance be it a publicly accessible instance or a back-end instance.

I would like to kindly ask for help in determining the possible security options for aws instances. I have no other resources being new to the department within work thus this post (recently moved from service delivery to infra)

Here is the security section of the form. please see the link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi6Mj.png

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: You should ask the people in your company who created the form.

Comment: That was certainly the first step but i failed to gather data due to cultural and political reasons. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Below are some items you may want to consider putting on the request form:

- Will this instance be internet facing or not?
- Who will need access to this system? How will they need to access it?
- Does the instance require encryption? Will PHI/PII data be stored on this instance?
- Does the request need approval from other departments or management?
- Will on-premise or data center resources need access to the instance (think VPN tunnels, etc, to create connections to the resources)
- Will additional logging be needed for the system?
- What applications will be required to be installed on the system?
- How long with the instance be needed, or date to terminate the instance when no longer needed?

I hope this helps.